# Angular 8 : Uncaught ReferenceError: OverlayScrollbars is not defined

Tags: angular, runtime-error, angular8

I am using a [overlay scrollbars](https://www.npmjs.com/package/overlayscrollbars-ngx) plugin in my angular app which has an extension called [OS-Scroll-chain](https://github.com/parsisolution/os-scroll-chain) to prevent scroll chaining. I already have installed all the packages.

I have added the cdn in my index.html -

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/os-scroll-chain@1/dist/os-scroll-chain.min.js"></script>
```

I have added these in my main.ts file

```
import * as scrollChain from 'os-scroll-chain';
import OverlayScrollbars from 'overlayscrollbars';
OverlayScrollbars.extension('scroll-chain', scrollChain );
```

Then in my custom overlay scrollbar component I have used this -

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this._osInstance = OverlayScrollbars(this.osTarget(), this.config || {});
  this._osInstance.addExt('scroll-chain', {vertical: true, horizontal: false})
}
```

Comment: Did you followed instruction for library installation ?

Comment: @Afsar, is there anything i am missing?

Comment: The way you included cdn in index , have you imported OverlayScrollbars in app.module ?

Comment: yes i have imported required modules